# preventing vim from destroying screen's scrollback buffer

Tags: vim, terminal, gnu-screen

when **not** using gnu screen, vim exits without littering my scroll back buffer. It vanishes, and all i get is a new bash prompt. everything that was on the screen before starting vim is there.

when its under screen, it will exit leaving its last screen on the scroll back, and worse, destroying the last screenful from the history.

how can i avoid this on screen?

i'm not really sure of the correct terms, maybe that is why i could not find anything alone.

Comment: I'm not sure of the right solution, but the terms to look for in Vim's help (perhaps using `:helpgrep`) are `t_ti` and `t_te`, and read `:help xterm-save-screen`. Also, you may need to set `altscreen on` in your ~/.screenrc. Hope that's enough to lead you to a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been confused by this before, too. I did some digging and found this answer on SO [1], which worked for me. Short answer: add the following line to your `~/.screenrc` file:

```
altscreen on
```

[1] [screen: how to turn on alternate screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17869443/202292)